# Can't set NSArray in segue

Tags: ios, nsarray, segue

DBPostListViewController has a NSArray *postList that needs to be set.

I keep getting

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewController setPostList:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e493d0
```

within the prepareForSegue for the setPostList function here:

```
    NSArray *tempAry = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"|@|"];
NSMutableArray *postArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[tempAry count]];
for (NSString *entry in tempAry) {
    DBPost *tempPost = [[DBPost alloc] initWithString:entry];
    [postArray addObject:tempPost];
}

DBPostListViewController *dest = [segue destinationViewController];
[dest setPostList:postArray];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message explains it:

```
-[UITableViewController setPostList:]: unrecognized selector
```

You send that message on these lines of code:

```
DBPostListViewController *dest = [segue destinationViewController];
[dest setPostList:postArray];
```

Objective-C is dynamically typed, so even though you've declared `dest` to be a `DBPostListViewController`, it could be any Objective-C object at all. And in this case it happens to be a `UITableViewController`.

You forgot to set the custom class in your storyboard file, so UIKit is just making an instance of a plain UITableViewController. Fix your storyboard and re-run your app.

Comment: THANK YOU. THANK YOU. THANK YOU.  This solved my hour long headache.